# Is there a way to hide a softkeyboard in windows 8 with html5/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I have a webapp with inputfields in it and I have only problems with the softkeyboard on Windows 8 mobile devices.

If a user click one of the inputfield the softkeyboard appears.

Now the user has three options, that I need to react on.

1. click in an other inputfield while keyboard is shown
2. scroll the content while the keyboard is shown
3. user hide the keyboard

   The first one I handeled with `input2.onClick()`.

   The second one is handeled by a scrollcontainer or browser itself(`input1.onBlur()` is fired)

   How can I handle the third one? Is there a way to handle this without using `input1.onBlur()`?

Comment: Why do you need to react to these? The user knows how their keyboard works and expects it to do as such, so what exactly do you want to do when you know? I'm also guessing that you could technically check that by checking the viewport height, which would have reduced and could catch all the above. Not sure though.

Comment: In my implementation I need to scroll the body manually by input.onClick(). Because the softkeyboard can overlay the inputfield.
And I need to scroll the content back to the origin position when the keyboard disappears.

Comment: That's really very non-standard behavior. But your viewport will change with the keyboard popping up, so instead of concentrating on the keyboard, look at the viewport size. That should be able to give you what you need.

Comment: Yes u are right. When I use a fullscreen webbapp on homescreen(http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-pin-chrome-web-apps-to-windows-8-start-screen/) I have the problem that the keyboard doesn't resize the viewport/browser window.